# Is there a way to utilize Java POM objects from a JavaScript Selenium test and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to utilize the pages from the Java POM codebase from the Javascript tests and vice versa - can the Java tests utilize the pages from the JavaScript POM in the completion of it's test?

Imagine a very large organization with many development areas. Up until this point they've been a Java shop and writing Selenium functional tests in Java. Now they're starting with JS and Node development and wish to write the Selenium tests for those apps in JS using WebDriverJS.

Now they wish to create Selenium tests which span these applications. These spanning tests may be written in either Java or JS, but they don't wish to re-create all of their Java page objects (POM) in the javascript codebase for those pages which need to be spanned.

An example...

1. Login pages are written in Java. Their Selenium tests are also in
   Java and the POM page classes are also written in Java.
2. The login page opens up to a JS app and therefore the app's pages are covered by a separate JS POM.
3. The JS app team writes a test but must navigate through the Java login pages by calling into the Java POM.
4. After login, the test will navigate the JS app using the POM classes
   defined for it within the JS codebase.